# Why XHR report the same time for status LOADING and DONE even if content downloading spend several seconds?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I hope to use XHR `readyStatus` change to monitor how long does an API call spend on server side response and content downloading.

```
let result = {};
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  result[xhr.readyState] = Date.now();
}
```

After one API call, the `result` looks like this:

```
{
  1: 1509274853725, // OPENED
  2: 1509274857991, // HEADERS_RECEIVED (~4.2s)
  3: 1509274857992, // LOADING
  4: 1509274857992  // DONE
}
```

But Chrome DevTool provides me different result:

I'd expect the difference between `HEADERS_RECEIVED` and `OPEN` is around 746ms and the difference between `DONE` and `HEADERS_RECEIVED` is around 3.52s.

Why the difference is so huge?

[image]

Comment: Can't repro on chrome 62 osX. What was the resource loaded?

Comment: @Kaiido, I am using Chrome 61 OSX. It's a RESTful API and I have used network throttling to increase the content downloading time.

Comment: That would have been a good thing to include in your question (the throttling) and I wouldn't search farther since I can now repro with, but not without. This functionality has no specs to tailor it, so it can't be called a bug, but IMM they messed something in how readyStates are handled with it. But anyway, you should be safe with your code.

Comment: @Kaiido, but I still have this problem after I turn off throttling.